# std::mapの初期化を綺麗にしたい

Tags: c++

C++のstd::mapのインスタンス(下記例では::table)の初期化コードをもう少し綺麗にしたいと思っています。
お知恵をお貸しください。
※C++17でお願いします

### 詳細

magic_enumというenumを便利に扱えるOSSを使用して、std::mapの静的インスタンス(下記例では::table)をグローバル関数(下記例では::trash::initialize)から汚らしく初期化しています。コンストラクタや初期化リストを使って綺麗に書きたいのですが、どうにも難しいので、書き方を教えてください。

型やデータは増えても構いませんし、同じ使い方が出来ればstd::mapでなくても構いません(でも出来れば依存は増やしたくないです)。

**追記**
(他でも使えるように)::tableの要素のfirstメンバの値を生成するロジックは今後変更される可能性があり、そのときでも有用となる書き方でお願いします。

#### コード

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <sstream>
#include <iomanip>
#include "magic_enum.hpp" // https://github.com/Neargye/magic_enum/releases/download/v0.8.1/magic_enum.hpp
using namespace std;
enum TCPSTATUS {
    UNKNOWN, ESTABLISHED, SYN_SENT, SYN_RECV, FIN_WAIT1, FIN_WAIT2, TIME_WAIT, CLOSE, CLOSE_WAIT, LAST_ACK, LISTEN, CLOSING,
};
map<string, TCPSTATUS> table;
namespace trash {
    void* initialize() {
        magic_enum::enum_for_each<TCPSTATUS>([&] (auto val) {
            constexpr TCPSTATUS status = val;
            stringstream ss;
            ss << hex << uppercase << setw(2) << setfill('0') << magic_enum::enum_integer(status);
            table[ss.str()] = status;
        });
        return nullptr;
    }
    void* dummy = initialize();
}
int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    for (const auto& p: table) {
        cout << p.first << "->" << magic_enum::enum_name(p.second) << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

### 出力(参考)

```
00->UNKNOWN
01->ESTABLISHED
02->SYN_SENT
03->SYN_RECV
04->FIN_WAIT1
05->FIN_WAIT2
06->TIME_WAIT
07->CLOSE
08->CLOSE_WAIT
09->LAST_ACK
0A->LISTEN
0B->CLOSING
```

Comment: 綺麗は主観が入るのでオイラにとってのきれいとあなたにとってのきれいは全く違う可能性があるです。客観的表現ができると回答できる人が増えそう。

Comment: あなたの綺麗と私の綺麗は違います。「コンストラクタや初期化リストを使って綺麗に書きたい」とは書いているので、その範囲であなたが綺麗だと思うコードを書いて頂ければOKです。

Comment: enumの整数値の16進数2桁の文字列からenumの整数値への対応ができればよいのでしょうか?

Comment: int32_tさんへ。ああ、そういうmapになってますね。キーとなる文字列の生成ロジックは可変であるとお考えください。質問文後で修正します。

Comment: 質問の主観性が高いからクローズとか意味が分かりませんね。
クローズされなくて困る話ではありません。
モデレーターの主観だけでクローズしていることの方が問題です。

Comment: 質問のクローズはあくまで "一時保留" の状態であり、(基本的には) モデレーターの独断ではなくこのサイトの参加者による投票で判断されます。 / dameo さん自身が 「あなたの綺麗と私の綺麗は違う」と書いている通り、"綺麗な" という修飾語によって「主観的な」答えしか集まらないと判断されている可能性があります。もしコンストラクタ等の書き方が分からないという事であれば、そちらを目立つような文書に見直してもらった方が意図が伝わりやすいと思います。 / クローズされたからといって (ほぼ同じまま) 別の質問をしても、懸念点が改善されないままだと同じようにクローズされてしまう可能性があります。まずは既存の質問を編集することを優先してみてください。

Comment: 質問内容に全く不備はありません。
クローズ判断をした人がモデレータかどうかも関係ありません。
クローズする意味ががないと言ってるだけなのです。

Comment: 何にせよ、クローズされるとシステム上、新規回答は受け付けられなくなります。質問文が改善されない限りクローズが撤回されることはありません。またクローズ状態で10日くらい経過すると、今度はシステムによって削除されます。あと、別スレッドの方ですが、マイナス票が多くなると一覧から表示されなくなります。削除はされませんが誰の目にもとまらなくなるわけです。

Comment: まだ言ってるし。。。どこも不備なんてありませんよ。言い掛かりはやめてください。

Comment: @sayuri 軽微な修正です：質問がクローズされても、得票がプラスの回答が既についていれば自動削除されません。 https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/roomba

Comment: このサイトでは、回答が主観的にしか行えないというのはクローズ理由になります。質問者さんがまっとうな質問だと考えているかどうかとは別の判断基準であり、質問者さんがサイトから去った後も Q&A を継続的にメンテナンスするために要求している条件であるとお考えください。詳細はこちら: https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask また、クローズに納得できない場合はそのことを主張するための [メタ](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/) という場所があり、こちらで詳細を詰めることができます。コメントはあまり長い議論には向かないので、ご意見ありましたらメタまでよろしくお願いいたします。個人的にはこのご質問については、どういう書き方を避けたいのかを言語化して書いてあるのでクローズするほどではないかなと思っています。

Comment: nekketsuuuさんへ。このような話をしたいわけではないのですが、「このサイトでは、回答が主観的にしか行えないというのはクローズ理由になります」の根拠を示していただけないですか？行動規範にもガイドラインにもないように見えます。

Comment: https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask や https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions です。https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/09/29/good-subjective-bad-subjective/ や https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/01/17/real-questions-have-answers/ もこの問題についてよく参考にされる記事になります。

Comment: ご説明ありがとうございます。行動規範にもガイドラインにもありませんが、別途確かに記述がありますね。ただ、「綺麗に」の一言で質問内容を「主観的」と断定するほどの話ではないと思いますよ。主観的かどうかというより、正解が一意でない問題は杓子定規に切り捨てる判断というのに近いのかと思います。問題としているのは議論している(攻撃している)かどうかであって、意見や理由の説明、またその個人的な評価ではないと思いますが、諍いとの区別が難しく、システム的には許容できないということなのかと理解しました。今回の件が実際に該当するかどうかは置いておいて、その判断の責を負う方が「主観的だ(面倒だ)」と判断したなら仕方ないですね。

Comment: あといろいろ解決しそうにないので、このまま放置で構いません。

Answer (score 5):

C++17の範囲でとなると[インライン変数](https://cpprefjp.github.io/lang/cpp17/inline_variables.html)を使って

```
static inline auto const table = [] {
    std::map<std::string, TCPSTATUS> table;
    for (auto e : magic_enum::enum_values<TCPSTATUS>()) {
        std::stringstream ss;
        ss << std::hex << std::uppercase << std::setw(2) << std::setfill('0') << e;
        table[ss.str()] = e;
    }
    return table;
}();
```

これぐらいですかね。C++20の[`std::format()`](https://cpprefjp.github.io/reference/format/format.html)を使用できれば

```
static inline auto const table = [] {
    std::map<std::string, TCPSTATUS> table;
    for (auto e : magic_enum::enum_values<TCPSTATUS>())
        table[std::format("{:02X}", int(e))] = e;
    return table;
}();
```

もっと簡単に済ませられます。

Comment: gcc 10.3.0でビルドしたところ、stringstreamのstr()が失敗するようです。<<演算子の戻り値の型がstringstreamではないからなのかもしれません。
もし、私の勘違いでなければstringstreamのインスタンスを宣言しても問題ないと思うので、修正お願いします。
あと今回の要件でインライン変数は別に使用しなくても大丈夫です(したほうがいいですが)。

Comment: 修正確認しました。
C++17でもオプション指定して使ってるときがあるくらいなのでC++20はまだ…。
個人的にはmapインスタンスを別に作らないと構築できないのが少し気になりますが、実装が簡潔＝綺麗というところなのでしょうね。

Comment: クローズされた質問のコメント欄で新しく議論が生まれていたため、この部分をチャットに移動しました。新しい疑問点がある場合は別途新しい質問としてご投稿ください。コメント欄は長い議論をするための場所ではないためです。
https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/140888/discussion-on-answer-by-sayuri-stdmap